# How to initialize an array of integers?

Tags: verilog

I have:

```
integer test[7:0];
```

but I cannot do:

```
test[0] = 0;
```

or

```
assign test[0] = 0;
```

or

```
intial
begin
test[0]=0;
end
```

or

```
integer test[7:0] = {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0};
```

Any ideas? Just using 0 as an example, I need it to be 26, 40, 32, 18, 50, 0, 20, 12

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are you sure `initial` doesn't work (you might have a typo in there...)?

```
initial begin
  for(int i=0; i<8; i++) begin
    test[i] = i;
  end
  $display(test[4]);
end
```

In systemverilog, something like the following will work. These are known as "Assignment Patterns":

```
integer test[7:0] = '{26, 40, 32, 18, 50, 0, 20, 12}; // note the '
```

I doubt either of the above are synthesisable, except maybe when targeting an FPGA.

Comment: Does `i` need to be declared?

Comment: the `i` is declared in the `for` statement, although it should actually be `integer i`.